# What does it mean for a break to appear AS a switch body?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, break

From the standard, emphasis mine:

> Constraints
>
> A break statement shall appear only in **or as** a switch body or loop body.

[https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.3p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.3p1)

I understand what it means for a break statement to appear in a switch body, but AS a switch body? I don't understand what this means. And the same question for loop body.

Comment: Or e.g. `for(i=0; i<7; i++) break;` which is legal.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hahaha, was it that simple? :D Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It means that

```
for(int i = 0; i < 42; i++)
    break;
```

is legal.

Answer (score 3):

It just means that the `break` can be the only statement in the switch body.

Comment: It's so obvious when you say it. I just could not see it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it refers to versions with no compound statement. That is:

```
switch(5) 
  break;
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  break;
```

It's nonsense code but valid C.

Answer (score 0):

A break statement can be the only statement appearing in a `switch` statement's  or a loop's body. In such cases, that break statement comprises of the entire body of the switch body or loop's body and therefore it can appear **as** the entire body of the statement. Or the other way, the break statement can be one or more of the statements contributing to the body among other statements and hence **in** the body. For instance,

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    break; // This is the entire body of this loop
}
```

Although the above code may not make sense, it is valid C.
Also,

```
switch(x) case 0: break;
```

In both the above examples, `break` statement **is** the body of the loop and of the switch.

### Update

The `break` in the second `switch` example is the only statement in the switch's body. The `case 0` part is a label. Although the labels have meaning inside a switch statement, it does not constitute to the body of the statement. This is possibly also why once the switch matches a case, all subsequent cases are also executed until the end of the switch block unless you add a break statement.

If you try to compile the switch with just the `case` or `default` label:

```
switch(x) case 0:
```

GCC would give the following error:

```
error: label at end of compound statement
```

which means the `case` or `default` cannot exist without a statement(unless it falls through).

Comment: Your example with switch does not look like it's correct. There it's inside the body. It's not the body. See Lundins answer.

Comment: @klutt The `case 0` part is just a label for the only statement in the switch statement's body. It would make sense if you consider the label as something that complements the statement.

Comment: Yes I understood that. It was just that I thought that it stole focus from the issue. There was not really a need to use labels at all.

Comment: In neither of these does a `break` statement appears as the switch body. In the `for` example, the body is `{ break; }`, which is a compound statement, as defined in C 2018 6.8.2. The `break;` is only part of the statement. In the `swtich(x) case 0: break;` example, the body is `case 0: break;`, which is a labeled statement, as defined in 6.8.1. Using a label, `case 0:` forms a new statement, the same way `if (x) break;` is an `if` statement, not a `break` statement, and the `break;` is only a part of that statement, not the whole statement.

Comment: In particular, this statement is incorrect or misleading: “Although the labels have meaning inside a switch statement, it does not constitute to the body of the statement.” Per C 2018 6.8.1, `case 0: break;` is a statement (which contains the statement `break;`), and per C 2018 6.8.4, it constitutes the body of the `switch` statement.